# can't run shell_exec(npm run production) from laravel controller on plesk server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, plesk

So I'm just trying to run shell_exec(/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/npm run production) on a plesk server from my laravel php controller after editing some text and css codes through php so the vue files get compiled again and the changes are being displayed but I just can't get it to work no matter what I try. Can't seem to get any error code or anything out of it either, I've just got no clue what to do at this point. Been searching some other posts in this forum or on google but can't really seem to find an answer. Was wondering if anyone here would know how to fix this.

When I run this code on localhost it works just fine, sorry if it's a noob question but I'm new to plesk. Just trying to get my laravel/vue app working online.

Comment: Plesk does not give you server admin I believe, you need to host through a VPS or alternative provider for shell execution (server admin). You're assigned resources via Plesk, you cannot manage them. You'll have to upload the relevant compiled sources to your server after running `npm run dev` locally.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Guess i'll have to look for a different host then since it's some sort of a CMS. Users have the ability to log in on their website and change text and pictures etc, don't think I'd still be able to let them do that if I can't run npm run production after they changed something.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. You'll need server admin but with this comes the responsibility of building it yourself, or using something like CPanel perhaps.